# Outlook Request Inbox and Other Items to be Shared

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, sharing

Is this place okay to ask questions about individual Applications?

My question is with Outlook 2016. I can see that you have the share button when focused on the calendar which lets you request rights to the persons calendar. Does this sort of option exist somewhere for other folders such as inbox, sent, etc.? If not in the desktop app is there something like this in OWA?

The reason why this would be useful is the support desk gets a lot of requests for setting permissions on various folders and we have to get authorization from HR. It would save a lot of time if we could just direct the user to request it directly from the person concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the folder you wan to share, then select Properties. The Inbox Properties window will open. Go to the Permissions tab and add the person you want to share the folder with. After adding the other user, select the person's name and set the permission level he/she should have. Also select Folder visible.

You can also do the same process by clicking on the menu bar on Folder then Folder Properties.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I am asking about a mechanism that might exist where the user can request permission to see a user's inbox. The user gets a message that allows them to share it. This exists for the calendars.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been assigned the appropriate permission to other user's mailbox, you may try to right-click your name in folder list->select Add shared folder->enter address of a user who shared folders with you->click Add in Outlook for web mail.
For more information, please check [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-open-other-user-folder-in-outlook-web/62a54361-43a2-4c98-be77-f142829f68b9).

Comment: Again, I'm not asking for this. In this scenario, the users have not assigned permission to their mailbox, they don't know how. The whole point is getting them to do it without us having to administer their mailboxes. I am asking if there exists a feature where the users can request access to folders other than calendar themselves.